# Bullets not following crosshair

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a top down shooter char and i am trying to have continuous fire and have the bullets follow the crosshair.

i used the continuous fire method from a space invaders game i was working on using corountines.
i am also using rewired to map out my controller.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 1;
    [SerializeField] float bulletSpeed = 1;
    [SerializeField] float fireRate = 1;

    public int playerId = 0;

    public GameObject crossHair;
    public GameObject arrowPrefab;

    private Player player;

    Coroutine firingCoroutine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(playerId);
    }

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("MoveHorizontal"), Input.GetAxis("MoveVertical"), 0.0f);

        AimAndShoot();

        transform.position = transform.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void AimAndShoot()
    {
        Vector3 aim = new Vector3(player.GetAxis("AimHorizontal"), player.GetAxis("AimVertical"), 0.0f);
        //Vector2 shootingDirection = new Vector2(player.GetAxis("AimHorizontal"), player.GetAxis("AimVertical"));

        if (aim.magnitude > 0.0f)
        {
            aim.Normalize(); //makes the crosshair move 1 unit from player
            aim *= 0.4f; // moves the crosshair closer to player.
            crossHair.transform.localPosition = aim;
            crossHair.SetActive(true);
            Fire();
        }
        else
        {
            crossHair.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void Fire()
    {
        if (player.GetButtonDown("Fire"))
        {
            if (firingCoroutine == null)
            {
                firingCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FireContinuously());
            }
        }
        if (player.GetButtonUp("Fire"))
        {
            if (firingCoroutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(firingCoroutine);
                firingCoroutine = null;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator FireContinuously()
    {
        Vector2 shootingDirection = new Vector2(player.GetAxis("AimHorizontal"), player.GetAxis("AimVertical"));

        while (true)
        {
            GameObject arrow = Instantiate(arrowPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity); // create/bullet/at player/no rotation
            arrow.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = shootingDirection * bulletSpeed;
            arrow.transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, Mathf.Atan2(shootingDirection.y, shootingDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
            // AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(shootSFX, Camera.main.transform.position, shootSFXVolume);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireRate);
            Destroy(arrow, 1.5f);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator FireRate()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
```

The problem i'm having is when i hold the trigger down it shoots continuously in the direction i originally aimed at, untill i release the trigger. The bullets/arrows don't shoot at the next spot i aim at unless i release the trigger and shoot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually looping back over the line

```
Vector2 shootingDirection = new Vector2(player.GetAxis("AimHorizontal"), player.GetAxis("AimVertical"));
```

You start your coroutine, set the aim, then your while(true) loop will run until the coroutine is stopped, if you want the aim to be updated then you also need to update the shootingDirection from within that loop.